# Doxygen @ref does not generate reference for #define macro-definitions in one file

Tags: macros, doxygen

I have a problem with @ref in oxygen documentation. In function description I have:

Doxygen 1.9.6

```
/// @param dwOptions type of allocation (0 - no special options needed, @ref ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR, @ref ALLOCOPTION_NO_ERASE, @ref ALLOCOPTION_EXTERNAL, @ref ALLOCOPTION_512C, @ref ALLOCOPTION_FOR_LWIP)
```

But there are no references in the generated documentation:

[image]

I also do not see any macro-definition from this file as well.

What could cause this problem?

### EDIT

I use almost standard settings (I use doxywizard). Those definitions are in the same .h file (further down)

I use `@ref` for myself (easier to read)

```C
// RTOS needs to know how to mask interrupts
// Most of the ioFunctions are NOT safe to call from an interrupt, exceptions are:
//  ioAllocateChunk is safe if ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR is set
//  ioIsValid and ioWasCanceled queries are valid
/** Allocate the chunk from ISR*/
#define ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR    0x00001000  
/** Do not zero the chunk buffer*/
#define ALLOCOPTION_NO_ERASE    0x00002000  
/** Allocate in external memory*/
#define ALLOCOPTION_EXTERNAL    0x00004000  
/** Allocate 512*/
#define ALLOCOPTION_512C        0x00008000  
/** Allocate the chunk to hold max size Ethernet frame*/
#define ALLOCOPTION_FOR_LWIP    0x00010000  

/// @brief Inializes memory pool. It must be called before memory pools are used
void ioAllocateInit(void);  // This must be called once at the beginning

/** 
* @brief Allocates memory chunk (@ref IOChunk_t) from the memory pool and zeroes the date
* @param dwBufferLength requested size of memory (or zero)
* @param dwOptions type of allocation (0 - no special options needed, @ref ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR, @ref ALLOCOPTION_NO_ERASE, @ref ALLOCOPTION_EXTERNAL, @ref ALLOCOPTION_512C, @ref ALLOCOPTION_FOR_LWIP)
* @param dwMaxWait maximum wait time for the chunk in RTOS ticks (usually 1/1000 sec)
* @return pointer to allocated @ref IOChunk_t or @ref NULL if allocation failed
* 
*/
IOChunk_t *ioCallocateChunk(unsigned long dwBufferLength,unsigned long dwOptions,unsigned dwMaxWait);

/// dwOptions  | Action
/// ------------- | -------------
/// 0  | Normal allocation
/// @ref ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR  | Allocation in the interrupt handler
/// @ref ALLOCOPTION_NO_ERASE  | ToDo
/// @ref ALLOCOPTION_EXTERNAL  | ToDo
/// @ref ALLOCOPTION_512C  | ToDo
/// @ref ALLOCOPTION_FOR_LWIP  | ToDo
/// @brief Allocates memory chunk (@ref IOChunk_t) from the memory pool
/// @param dwBufferLength requested size of memory (or zero)
/// @param dwOptions type of allocation (0 - no special options needed, @ref ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR, @ref ALLOCOPTION_NO_ERASE, @ref ALLOCOPTION_EXTERNAL, @ref ALLOCOPTION_512C, @ref ALLOCOPTION_FOR_LWIP)
/// @param dwMaxWait maxim wait for the chunk in RTOS ticks (usually 1/1000 sec)
/// @return pointer to allocated @ref IOChunk_t or @ref NULL if allocation failed
IOChunk_t *ioAllocateChunk(unsigned long dwBufferLength,unsigned long dwOptions,unsigned dwMaxWait);
```

Warnings (it cant find it indeed)

```
C:/doxygen_experiments/STM/drivers/hndCore.h:27: warning: documentation for unknown define DRV_CORE_H_DEFINED found.

C:/doxygen_experiments/STM/drivers/hndCore.h:355: warning: documentation for unknown define ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR found.

C:/doxygen_experiments/STM/drivers/hndCore.h:357: warning: documentation for unknown define ALLOCOPTION_NO_ERASE found.

C:/doxygen_experiments/STM/drivers/hndCore.h:359: warning: documentation for unknown define ALLOCOPTION_EXTERNAL found.

C:/doxygen_experiments/STM/drivers/hndCore.h:361: warning: documentation for unknown define ALLOCOPTION_512C found.

C:/doxygen_experiments/STM/drivers/hndCore.h:363: warning: documentation for unknown define ALLOCOPTION_FOR_LWIP found.
```

## CLOSING EDIT

It is probably a doxygen parser bug. It has disappeared when I added more comments to the file (in not relevant part of it). Closing the question as not longer needed

Comment: Which doxygen version are you using? What are the settings in your settings file diferent from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`). Where is e.g. `ALLOCOPTION_FROM_ISR`  specified? All in all a small, complete, example would be necessary to say more.

Comment: You don't even need to `ref` explicitly. Doxygen should handle references automagically unless you've broken something in documentation before those definitions. As @albert pointed, you better add all relevant parts for a better diagnostic.

Comment: @albert quite a bit project. I will try later to reduce it to one file.

Comment: @albert I have added the relevant part of the .h file

Comment: @Kozmotronik added part of the .h file. The macros are in the same file

Comment: I tried the code you posted and it actually generates nothing in the output, only a blank page with a file name. I didn't get those warnings at all.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I think it was a doxygen problem. It has gone away when I added more comments to the file. Thank you

Comment: When I run your example with a default `Doxyfile` in the 1.9.6 (or 1.9.7) version of doxygen I get no warnings about `NULL` and `IOChunk_t` which is logical as they are not documented in the shown chunck. I had to explicitly add `/// \file` command to get the info though.